# Samba not working: No route to host

Tags: samba

I've been trying for hours to get a share through Samba and now I'm very desperate. I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS just yesterday. Additionally FileMaker was installed. I think the problem is that the server is not accessible via port 445. The ufw is disabled. When I try to connect via smbclient from another server, I get the following error message:

```
do_connect: Connection to 10.10.10.243 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

With telnet almost the same error:

```
telnet 10.10.10.243 445
Trying 10.10.10.243...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

Here is the output of netstat:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | egrep "samba|smbd|nmbd|winbind"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1088/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1088/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1088/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1088/smbd
udp        0      0 10.10.10.255:137        0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.10.10.243:137        0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.10.10.255:138        0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.10.10.243:138        0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           1035/nmbd
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: no route to host means exactly what it says, your system doesn't know how to get to 10.10.10.243. Do you have a default gateway on the system you're connecting/telnetting from. Should be able to ping

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: Ping is coming through with no problem. In both directions.